# Can i code Assambly for x86 Windows from x64 Linux ?

Tags: linux, windows, assembly, intel, x86-16

i have 64bit Ubuntu but i need to code ASM code for Intel 8086 Windows... Is there any software or IDE or emulator you can suggest?

I know that there is different instructions for each kind of processor...

Comment: I think the last version of Microsoft Windows that you could run on the 8086 was Windows 3.0 back in 1990... pretty sure 3.1 required at least a 80286 to run. (Edit: yes. [Wikipedia agrees.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_3.1#Improvements_over_Windows_3.0))

Comment: Hm, I answered how to develop Windows applications from inside Linux, but are you really sure you want to write 8086 code? It is ancient processor as Michael already wrote.

Comment: BTW, as I can see, the title of the question mentions x86 Windows, so 8086 in the question body is maybe a mistake.

Comment: x86 Intel processors have same set of instructions that 8086 (i can be wrong so  sorry)

Answer (score 1):

At first, you always can compile your program in 32bit Windows PE executable, using the proper compiler. I don't know for other assemblers, but, for example, **[FASM](http://flatassembler.net)** can do it in easy.

The big problem is with the testing - i.e. how to run and debug the compiled program?

The only IDE I know that is able to compile, run and debug Windows and Linux applications in the same time, from Linux is **[Fresh IDE](http://fresh.flatassembler.net)** (it is based on FASM compiler). Fresh IDE is windows application, so you will need **[WINE](http://www.winehq.org/)** installed in order to use it (and it uses Wine in order to be able to run Windows applications from Linux).

As far as I know, WINE can run on 64bit Linux, but I never used it, so can't give any guides for installing it.

After installing WINE, install and configure Fresh IDE as described in the **[setup guide](http://fresh.flatassembler.net/index.cgi?page=content/articles/0_advanced_setup.txt#H2.)**.

NOTE: Fresh IDE is my product and I am possibly little bit biased. But it has the features described in this answer (and many more useful features as well). :)

Comment: Wine runs perfectly fine on 64bit Linux. And I use it to test my Windows code all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Specific assembly syntax is compiler specific.  You will need to investigate this for whichever compiler you're planning to use.  I am unaware of any specific IDE/emulator for this purpose in Linux, however you can use any editor of your choice (vi, emacs, eclipse, nano, textedit, etc) to write the text document which contains your code.  You could then transfer this to a windows machine with the appropriate compiler.  Unless you lack regular access to the compilation machine, however, it's likely more in your interest to work in the environment which you're going to compile to.

Comment: WINE might help. Actually, the instructions are the same (assuming x86 x86-64 family - not a literal 8086) but what we need to do with them varies with OS. Nasm, Yasm, Fasm, Jwasm, (and MinGW Gas and ld) will all "cross assemble". You definitely can produce Windows code on a Linux machine. Testing your gem may be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can write code on whatever machine you want.  Testing it is another story entirely.  In your case, you'll at least want to get a cross-assembler to build Windows binaries on your Linux machine, and then probably a VM running windows of some kind to test your program.  If you're going to the effort of setting up the VM, you can probably just use a native assembler there too.